# Is it possible to bind input to two variables at the same time in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

This is a typical Angular's Material `matInput`:

```html
<input matInput [(ngModel)]="model.property" name="property" />
```

Now to apply logic when the model changes, a common solution proposed by other developers in SO is to break *banana-in-the-box* into **property-binder** and **event-hook** expressions:

```html
<input matInput [ngModel]="model.property" (ngModelChange)="model.property=someLogic($event)" />
```

Based on this logic, I created a `digitGroup` function that gets the input number, puts commas in between each three numbers, and shows that in the `matInput` field.

However, the problem is that now the `model.property` is a string representing the digit-grouped number, rather than being a real JavaScript number, so in each place I need to access its value and do some mathematical operation on it, I need to `undigitGroup(model.property)` first.

Is it possible that I bind `matInput` to two properties of the `model` at the same time? That way I can have `model.property` for calculations and `model.digitGroupedProperty` to show to the user, both at the same time.

Comment: Can't you bind it to an instance of a class containing the two properties?

Comment: Leaving angular apart, can you devise the spec for such a control ? Maybe what you need requires an extension of the matInput control, which can take more properties and can be binded separately

Comment: @Isma, that's an option of course, but it needs extra work for each input and for a total solution of an application including admin panel, and user panel forms, it's not a good solution. Besides, in short terms I want to be able to separate **true value** from **shown value**. This will make room for better UI design with less code.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) to display the model transformed by `digitGroup` function without changing the model.

```
@Pipe({name: 'groupDigits'})
export class DigitGroupPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any) {
      // Call your digitGroup() function here, then return result
  }
}
```

Then use them like this:

```
<input matInput [ngModel]="model.property | groupDigits" (ngModelChange)="model.property=$event" />
```

That way, your `model` will not be mutated by your `digitGroup()` function, only on the view

Answer (score 3):

As *Jed Cua* said, you should be able to do it with pipe. But you can also do it *manually* with a local variable, having the local variable for user display and model property for calculations.

1. In your component, init a local variable **modelPropertyRaw** `modelPropertyRaw = digitGroup(model.property)` in *ngOnInit*
2. Bind input to local variable **modelPropertyRaw**
3. Add `(input)="onPropertyChange($event.target.value)"` to your input
4. In **onPropertyChange**, do `model.property = undigitGroup(modelPropertyRaw)`

This separate *true value* from *shown value*.

---

**EDIT:** In your *.html* file

```
<!-- Replaced (ngOnModelChange) by (input). Notice that you are not forced to pass the event for the behavior we want -->
<input matInput [ngModel]="modelPropertyRaw" (input)="onPropertyChange($event.target.value)" />
```

In your *.ts* file

Add a local variable *modelPropertyRaw* (you can also add it as an attribute of your model class)

```
modelPropertyRaw: string;
```

Add *onPropertyChange* function like this

```
onPropertyChange(inputText: string)
{
  model.property = undigitGroup(modelPropertyRaw);
}
```

That's it ! If you don't want component local variable, add propertyRaw as an attribute of model and use it instead of modelPropertyRaw in this code

Comment: in item 1, did you mean `model.modelPropertyRaw = digitGroup(model.property)`?

Comment: Nope, because modelPropertyRaw is a local variable of your **component**, you could make a `modelPropertyRaw` attribute in your **Model** class, but if *shown value* is only used in one component, I'll definitely put it as an attribute of this component instead. (But there was also a little mistake in my post, I edited for more clarity)

Comment: I did what you said and couldn't make it work. I do really appreciate it if you provide a fiddler.

Comment: @mohammadrostamisiahgeli I edited my answer with some code